# How to update firebasemessagingservice to latest version?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get an error says "error: class, interface, or enum expected" and I found out its from the firebasemessagingservice needs to be updated and I don't know how to do it. Please help.

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you put an extra " } " in your code. remove it and recompile

Correct code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
    }

}
```

Comment: You miss the class declaration. for "sendRegistrationToServer" this method, because of your extra "}". that's why the error happened

Comment: No the error still showing I think the firebase settings are outdated I need to update them but I don't know how

Comment: Did you add your service to AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yeah I added the AndroidManifest.xml  in the comment section

Comment: why did you add two MyFirebaseMessagingService? remove one

Comment: what is the current error?, could you post your whole error?

Answer (score 0):

And here is the androidManifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=""
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Disable opening of launcher Activity -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
        android:value="DISABLE" />

    <activity
        android:name=""
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=""
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=""
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tools.vactivities.ActivityRecipesDetail"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />

    <!--admob-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <!--fcm-->
    <service android:name="com.tools.notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.tools.notification.NotificationExtenderExample"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```